# What is the correct way to store, increment and reuse an index

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I am in the process of building my first bespoke PHP/MySQL app. It is a kind of survey application for vehicle testing.

The survey itself is built via queries to the database where I have stored the questions and using a loop they get outputted to the page each with a unique ID and name.

All is working so far. I can successfully submit results and access the $_POST array and can see answers stored against the correct keys.

I am at the stage now where I wish to save the results.

My intention is to use a table to record the results using one row per answer. The columns I plan on using are survey_id, question_id (the key from the array), question_answer.

My question is how do I correctly store and increment the survey ID itself? If I was recording the survey in such a way that a single row would contain all of the results for a single survey I could auto increment the survey_id field but when I was designing the app I did not think this would be the most robust way to store results. Each survey will be in excess of 100 rows each and any changes to the layout of the survey down the line would be tricky to implement (I suspect).

My initial thought was to create a stand alone table to record and increment survey ID's and then to query this to populate the survey_id in the results table.

I would love to hear the best practise to achieving this.

Comment: The survey_id is a foreign key.  You don't increment that in the dependant table, only in the master table and then refer to the master table value in your dependant table.

Comment: So then would using a separate 'survey' table that records and increments they key be best? Then this gets used in the child table as a foreign key as you suggest?

Comment: Yes, you'd have separate tables to represent the survey as a whole, the questions associated with a given survey, and the answers people have left for the questions.  This is one of the core benefits of relational databases, they let you model the relationships between data as well as storing the data itself.

Comment: That's exactly what I am going to do. I've just designed it and I have a 'survey' table with 12 rows to store the non-question elements of the survey and then a new table to record just the answers using the ID from 'surveys'. It seems to obvious now! Thanks.

Comment: That's the problem with a lot of programming, it seems impenetrable until you get it, then it seems obvious :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to have three tables:

- Surveys
- Questions
- Answers

`Surveys` would probably have a survey ID, user that created the survey, so on. `Questions` would have a question ID, the survey ID that the question is for, and what the question is asking. Lastly, `Answers` would have the answers to the questions, most likely having an answer ID, question ID, user who answered it and their answer.

In essence, your original idea of

> create a stand alone table to record and increment survey ID's and then to query this to populate the survey_id in the results table.

is the right one in this circumstance.

Comment: Brilliant! I wasn't sure if this was the best practise or not. I will follow your suggestion and record some additional survey details in the survey table besides just the ID such as the user, etc. Thanks for your feedback.